# Probable mistake in calculation of maxima

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

**QUESTION:** Given function is $$E=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{F^2}{m}\cdot \frac{\omega_0^2+\omega^2}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+4\alpha^2\omega^2}$$

We have to maximise $E$ with respect to $\omega$.

**MY ATTEMPT FOR SOLUTION:** $$E=\frac{F^2}{4m}\cdot \phi(\omega^2)$$

Now, $\frac{dE}{d(\omega^2)}=\frac{d\{\phi(\omega^2)\}}{d(\omega^2)}=0$ when $E$ is maximum.

So we have that $$\frac{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+4\alpha^2\omega^2-(\omega_0^2+\omega^2)\left[-2(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)+4\alpha^2\right]}{\left[(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+4\alpha^2\omega^2\right]^2}=0$$
Or, $$(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2-4\alpha^2\omega_0^2+2(\omega_0^2+\omega^2)(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)=0$$
Or, $$(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)\left[(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)+2(\omega_0^2+\omega^2)\right]=4\alpha^2\omega_0^2$$
Or, $$(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)(3\omega_0^2+\omega^2)=4\alpha^2\omega_0^2$$

This results in a Fourth degree equation in $\omega$ and it yields a very complex result.

But in the book, it is given that $E$ is maximum when $\omega=\omega_0$.

Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Comment: i don't understand which rule do you used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do be scared of 4th order. I think you are correct so far.

$$(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)(3\omega_0^2+\omega^2)=4\alpha^2\omega_0^2$$
$$(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)(3\omega_0^2+\omega^2)=3\omega_0^4-2\omega_0^2\omega^2-\omega_0^4$$
$$3\omega_0^4-2\omega_0^2\omega^2-\omega_0^4=4\alpha^2\omega_0^2$$
$$\omega_0^4+2\omega_0^2\omega^2+4\alpha^2\omega_0^2-3\omega_0^4=0$$
$$\omega^2=\frac{-2\omega_0^2\pm\sqrt{4\omega_0^4-4(4\alpha^2\omega_0^2-3\omega_0^4)}}2$$
because $\omega^2\ge0$
$$\omega^2=\frac{-2\omega_0^2+\sqrt{16\omega_0^4-16\alpha^2\omega_0^2}}2$$

As you can then see, when $\alpha=0$, you can get $\omega=\omega_0$. Otherwise, $\omega\lt\omega_0$. You book only gives you one results when damping force is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, since $\omega^2$ is strictly increasing, it suffices to change variables $x = \omega^2$ and minimize
$$
f(x) = \frac{A+x}{(A-x)^2+Bx}
$$